# How do I know in AppDelegate when UIViewController transit to another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

Is there anyway to know in AppDelegate that new UIViewController is pushed without calling any extra method in AppDelegate and UIViewController?

Can AppDelegate be able to know which new UIViewController is being pushed without writing any piece of code in particular UIViewController?

Comment: ViewControllers gets pushed and popped from their respective Navigation stack owned by Navigation Controllers. Where as AppDelegate is just a  delegate to UIApplication objects life events. They aren't related at all What are you trying to achieve ??

Comment: Really without calling any extra method?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have an hacky way for you as you don't want to write any code in your viewcontrollers. Check out my category below for you

**UINavigationController+PushNotifier.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationController (PushNotifier)
extern void PJSwizzleMethod(Class cls, SEL originalSelector, SEL swizzledSelector);

@end
```

**UINavigationController+PushNotifier.m**

```
#import "UINavigationController+PushNotifier.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@implementation UINavigationController (PushNotifier)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        PJSwizzleMethod([self class],
                        @selector(pushViewController:animated:),
                        @selector(pj_pushViewController:animated:));
    });
}

- (void)pj_pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    //notify your Application Delegate
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewControllerWillPush" object:nil userInfo:@{@"pushingViewController":viewController}];
    return [self pj_pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

@end

void PJSwizzleMethod(Class cls, SEL originalSelector, SEL swizzledSelector)
{
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, swizzledSelector);

    BOOL didAddMethod =
    class_addMethod(cls,
                    originalSelector,
                    method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                    method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

    if (didAddMethod) {
        class_replaceMethod(cls,
                            swizzledSelector,
                            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This will only work if you use navigation controller and push/show view controller

Answer (score -2):

There is no proper way to do that but as a workaround you could use this method :

> ```
> func application (_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
>     guard let vc = (window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController) else {
>         return .portrait // your default orientation, to update according to your needs
>     }
>     if (vc.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("The class you are looking to")!)) {
> // Here you can put any code you want, your view controller was just pushed
>         return .allButUpsideDown
>     }
>     return .portrait
>  //   return the orientation you want
> }
> ```

The problem is that you will need to do a cast for EACH viewController in your app, imo doing some custom code would be cleaner and more suited to your needs.

Comment: How does your solution detect if any view controller is pushed in the app, like it's asked in the question?

Comment: @AuRis If you cast succeed it means your view controller was just pushed, i thought this was clear enough :/

Comment: First of all your code won't compile, because you're missing one brace. Secondly, I wouldn't call it even a workaround if you need to check for each possible class. And most importantly if the cast succeeds does not mean the view controller was pushed.

Comment: My bad, i removed some code and forgot to check it. On the other hand the code is doing what is asked, i use it to know when my videoPlayer is on screen. There is no other way to do it in appDelegate without using a custom method. Are you bored? Because you seem very agressive mate.

Comment: Haha dude, I am just pointing out that your code does not provide a solution to the answer.

Comment: Well it does, sorry you don't see it that way :/